# How to print array elements in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, code-snippets

I have tried this to print array objects echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ath_role', TRUE); but it only returns a word array.

Answer (score 1):

You should use print_r() or var_dum() for printing array.

also you can use this for formatted array print.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```